# Encounter ORA-00600 when moving tablespace in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, tablespace, ora-00600

I need to change the tablespace when client create table with specified tablespace, so I write the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_MON_DDL
AFTER CREATE OR ALTER ON DATABASE
DECLARE
SQL_TABLESPACE_NAME VARCHAR2(60);
INDEX_TABSP_NAME VARCHAR2(60);
CUR_USER VARCHAR2(100);
SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(2000);
V_SQL VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA'),'') INTO CUR_USER FROM DUAL;
IF SYSEVENT = 'CREATE' OR SYSEVENT = 'ALTER' THEN
    IF ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE ='TABLE' THEN
            SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME INTO SQL_TABLESPACE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME=ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME;
            IF INSTR(SQL_TABLESPACE_NAME,'_'||CUR_USER)=0 THEN
                V_SQL:='ALTER TABLE ' || 'FOO.' || ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME||' MOVE TABLESPACE '||SQL_TABLESPACE_NAME||'_'||CUR_USER||'';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
            END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

And run the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE FOO.ADMIN_EMP1 (id  NUMBER(5), name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL) TABLESPACE TB;
```

CUR_USER is FOO. So the trigger will move the table from tablespace TB to TB_FOO, but when the trigger run the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL, it came out to be the following.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17058], [0x06406F530], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I can't figure out why. And I am finding if there are other solutions to solve my case.

Comment: ORA-00600 is *usually* bad luck - Oracle bug, which means that you should contact Oracle. Though, what is ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE? You use it, but never declare it. Before executing it, display V_SQL value on the screen (DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE), check whether it looks OK, execute it directly from SQL*Plus and see what happens.

Comment: Everything goes right when I create a table and then move the tablespace, it just not work in the trigger. ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE is the variable offered by PL/SQL.